# Excel 2013 – put "N/A" in all cells in a row based on the input in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I created an Excel database. At a certain column, I can only input Yes/No. What I want to happen is if I put "No", all cells after that cell for that row will show N/A. However, if the answer is Yes, I want those cells to accept be able to accept input.

Given that this has to be true for the whole table and for every new row added and that there is a possibility I would go back and change my answer to "No", I cannot rely on a formula. How can I consistently make sure that the cell values adjust depending on whether the important cell contains a Yes or No?

Example:

```
Cols    A     B     C      D     E
Row1   Yes   12    Some   1     3
Row2   No    N/A   N/A    N/A   N/A
```

Note: In case it might affect anything, Columns D and E have Data Validation and can only accept answers from a pre-set list. I have included "N/A" on this list just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an event procedure in VBA (of type Worksheet_SelectionChange), check if column A in your table is the target area, and conditionally fill the cells with 'N/A' text. But this would discard all values previously entered.

As an easy alternative, I suggest using Conditional Formats. The condition is

```
=(TOLOWER($A4)<>"yes")
```

for cells in row 4, and the format if True would be an identical text color and pattern color. This way, all content is hidden from view while the values are not touched. After all, this is for guiding a person on data input, visually.

Comment: Yes, I settled for Conditional Formatting to gray out the remaining cells for that row if the A cell contains 'No' to discourage others from filling in the remaining spots. Unfortunately, as the table is ever-expanding for new entries, I would have to extend the range of the rule when it happens (e.g. $B$2:$E$500 -> $B$2:$E$1000 when I reach 500 rows). Also the only condition I used was a simple =$A1=No to check if True. If you would offer a more elegant solution, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto your conditional formatting question: Your range can be an equation, instead of a fixed range. This will make the OFFSET function particularly useful, as you can have the conditional formatting automatically expand to include your selection. For example:

```
=Offset(A1,0,0,CountA(A1:A1000),1)
```

Will automatically expand to include everything in column A, up to row 1000. If you want it to expand horizontally

```
=Offset(A1,0,0,1,CountA(A1:DZ1))
```

Etc.

This will break if you have column breaks in the middle. Not sure how well it handles with merged cells as well (Haven't tested it yet) For issues like that, try something like this: (Example given with 5 blank rows for spacing reasons)

```
=Offset(A1,0,0,CountA(A1:A1000)+5,1)
```

Etc. Hopefully that'll help with your "but I need to keep expanding it" issue.

Comment: Thank you, I will consider this. Merged cells will not be an issue, as I avoid using them due to how they mess up Pivot tables. However, as I still insert columns in the middle of the table for adjustments, I will wait until the table reaches 'finality' before adding this conditional formatting.

Comment: You can add columns in the middle and it'll adjust for the columns - what I was talking about was columns that are completely blank.